# Android package-name issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-package-managers

I am new to android and learning with a project, I have a doubt and if someone could help me it would be really helpful.

when I change the package name the app works but it doesn't allow me to goto next activity.

below is the logcat details, no error just showing this.

I have changed the package name from `"com.ringdroid"` to `"com.ringxskah"`.
Even after that no solution.

[image]

Comment: post you code to understand better

Comment: Change package name in AndroidMenifest.xml, build.gradle(Module:app) and every Activity class that you have.

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir I did that ,the app get's installed and shows the main activity too but dosen't work ,whenever i press anywhere on the activity ,it stays there only

Comment: @Kathi this is the project which I am using - https://github.com/google/ringdroid

Comment: 1-In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon ( Gears icon ),

2-Uncheck / De-select the Compact Empty Middle Packages option

Comment: You can take help from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: @rahulkumar I understand that you are trying to make duplicate of ringdroid  with your own package, how did you change package name ? `Rename` ? Does this effects in all you project ?

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir I did that sir, not working for me.

Comment: @Kathi I have renamed the package name using the refractor and  changed the applicationID in build gradle.Then also it's not working for me..

Comment: Try this: 
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(packageName+"." + NameOfClass); 
intent.setClass(this, clazz);

Comment: Can yoou please elaborate more on that ?

Comment: Please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/5550161

Comment: @rahulkumar use 
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(packageName+"." + NameOfClass);

intent.setClass(this, clazz);

 replacing 

intent.setClassName("com.ringdroid","com.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");

 to start new Activity